# How to balance and parallelize the processing of multiple sequential streams of data

Tags: .net, multithreading, performance, .net-4.0, task-parallel-library

I have a single stream of data that must be processed as quickly as possible.  The single stream contains data from up to 200 sources.  Not all the sources produce the same amount of data and the rate can vary.

As an initial attempt I decided to create 10 (sort of based on the server spec, dual quad core), long running Tasks.  Each Task would read from a BlockCollection.  Before starting I created a map so that as data is received on the inbound stream I know which BlockingCollection to add that sources data to.

The problem, I think, is that I don't know upfront which source will produce the most data and indeed this can change over time I saw that some collections were very empty, while others were receiving many more updates.

If I have 8 hardware threads available and I've created about 10 queues and Tasks aren't bound to a thread (again not sure if this is true with `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`), then even if one queue is not busy the other busy queue can't make use of the spare thread as in theory I could end up processing a piece of data out of sequence.

Would I be better just creating a Task and Blocking collection for each source, then the TPL can make best use of the threads available as the data is at its most segregated?

My other alternative was to somehow workout on past stats and various external/human info how best to spread the sources amongst a finite set of BlockingCollections/Tasks and then adjust the mapping over time.

I hope I've explained my scenario well enough.

I'm using a class that encapsulates the [BlockingCollection and Task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243872/how-to-correctly-clean-up-after-long-running-task-is-cancelled)

I have what could be visualised as 40+ streams interlaced which if split be processed at the same time (as long as each stream is kept in it's own sequence), but there are many more streams than available hardware threads.

### EDIT - Attempt to clarify my query

To try and clarify what I'm looking for.  I'm currently spliting sources into sub groups, effectively, and allocating each group it's own queue.  My question is really: How many groups to create?  If I have 200 sources, should I create 200 groups (which is then 200 Tasks and Blocking collections) and then let the TPL run around like a mad man allocating threads where it can as each Task gets it's cpu time.  Or am I better off allocating 1 group per underlying hardware thread?

Comment: So wait, do you have a single input stream or multiple streams?

Comment: Single stream initially. I've added a paragraph to try and explain myself better. Thanks for reading.

Comment: Is this a consolidated feed of stock prices?

Comment: What are your exact requirements about ordering? Can you start processing second item from a source before you finish first one? What are you optimizing for? Only throughput or does latency matter too? Why can't you simply use one shared `BlockingCollection`?

Comment: @rjdevereux yes that's a perfect way to describe the data stream.

Comment: @svick no, if I shared the collection then possibly a thread could process the data out of sequence.  Latency does need to be kept to a minimum, but not at the expense of any one set of data.

Comment: So your preferred processing order is 1st item from source 1, 1st items from source 2, …, 1st item from source n, 2nd item from source 1, etc. (assuming no 2nd item is processed before 1st item from some source)?

Comment: Well ideally I'd process them as they came in with as many worker threads as I needed processing but the problem arose when, thread 5 took an item that was from the same source as the item thread 2 was processing. Thread 5 would need to know to wait for thread 2 to finish.  Also if too many items from one source came in, on a single queue, it would block items from other sources getting processed.  So dumping them in predefined bucket queues allow the control to dump the queue if it got backed up.

I just wondered if I could create a Queue and Task per srcand let the TPL allocate threads.

Comment: Would I be better off just starting a queue in line with `Environment.ProcessorCount`??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you created one `Task` and one queue for each source, that should work, as long as that `Task` finishes when the queue is empty. You will know for sure that ordering for items in one source is maintained and you should have full CPU utilization when it's necessary. But if all threads are currently processing, and new data comes from a low-frequency source, you might wait a long time before that data is processed.

If that is a problem for you, you should manage the exact order of processing by yourself and not rely on `Task`s. To do that, you could have one global queue and then a local queue for each source. To maintain the order, there can be at most one data item in the global queue or currently processing. When processing of an item is done, an item is moved from the correct local queue to the global queue, if possible. This way, you should get more fair order of processing the data.

The code could look like this:

```
class SourcesManager<T>
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<Tuple<T, Source<T>>> m_queue =
        new BlockingCollection<Tuple<T, Source<T>>>();

    public Source<T> CreateSource()
    {
        return new Source<T>(m_queue);
    }

    // blocks if no items are available and Complete() hasn't been called
    public bool TryProcess(Action<T> action)
    {
        Tuple<T, Source<T>> tuple;
        if (m_queue.TryTake(out tuple, Timeout.Infinite))
        {
            action(tuple.Item1);
            tuple.Item2.TryDequeue();
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void Complete()
    {
        m_queue.CompleteAdding();
    }
}

class Source<T>
{
    private readonly Queue<T> m_localQueue = new Queue<T>();
    private readonly BlockingCollection<Tuple<T, Source<T>>> m_managerQueue;
    private volatile bool m_managerHasData = false;

    internal Source(BlockingCollection<Tuple<T, Source<T>>> managerQueue)
    {
        m_managerQueue = managerQueue;
    }

    public void Enqueue(T data)
    {
        lock (m_localQueue)
        {
            if (!m_managerHasData)
            {
                m_managerQueue.Add(Tuple.Create(data, this));
                m_managerHasData = true;
            }
            else
                m_localQueue.Enqueue(data);
        }
    }

    internal bool TryDequeue()
    {
        lock (m_localQueue)
        {
            if (m_localQueue.Count == 0)
            {
                m_managerHasData = false;
                return false;
            }

            m_managerQueue.Add(Tuple.Create(m_localQueue.Dequeue(), this));
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As @rjdevereux observed in his comment on the main post this is a continuous stream of data much like stock prices, I currently has a global queue with one task pulling from that and placing each item into a predefined local queue, which in turn has a task processing, much like your suggestion.  My query is really how to determine how best to partition my sources to allow the TPL to make the best use of the underlying hardware.

Comment: Well, I think my answer actually answers that: I think having one global queue and then queues for sources would accomplish exactly that.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I'm doing already, my query is how many local queues to craete to best make use of the underlying hardware/without starving the rest of the system.  I've added an update to the question to try and explain my query better.

Comment: I think it's not what you're doing. I'm saying you should have one local queue per source and process the data from one global queue. If you have a separate queue for each task, that could indeed lead to starvation. But I think there is no need to do that, each task can process items directly from the global queue.

Comment: Could you reinterate what you mean by 'one local queue per source and process the data from one global queue'.  So take the data from the stream, determine the source, place into it's local queue and then what?  Could you provide an example of how your above code would be used, I'm unclear where the Tasks are reading from the local queues?

Comment: @MattC, yes, that's what I meant. And tasks are not reading from local queues directly. Each task calls `SourcesManager.TryProcess()` in a loop, which takes an item from the global queue, processes it and then moves one item from the correct local queue to the global one (by calling `Source.TryDequeue()`).

Comment: I think I'm beginning to understand.  However, A couple questions.  How many Tasks to start reading from the global queue?  And isn't there a chance that a subsequent Task could pull an item from the global queue and process it before a previous Task has finished, thereby breaking the sequence?  Also, the stream is continuous, if there is nothing in the queue then the Tasks should not end..but wait.

Comment: @MattC: The sequence can't be broken since there is never more than one item from each source in the global que. While an item is processed there is no item from the same source in the global que.

Comment: @MattC 1. adrianm is right about the order of operations. 2. I modified the code to make it block if no items are available. 3. If the processing is CPU-bound, you should use as many tasks as you have cores (`Environment.ProcessorCount`).

Comment: @svick Ah I see...I'll rig a version of this inside a replacement class and use that and see how it performs and get back to you.

Comment: @svick - We're running a test, so far looks promising, I've tweaked it a little to add some stats reporting.  One, more question.
If the action supplied to `TryProcess` includes an operation that is I/O Bound (FileSys or UDP Send), would you consider upping the number of tasks?

Comment: @svick - forgot to add, how would sending UDP to a port on the same machine affect the CPU to I/O usage?

Answer (score 1):

I would personally leverage TPL Dataflow here and just define an `ActionBlock<T>` that reprsents your work and link a `BufferBlock<T>` "in front" of it to prevent over saturation by the various producers. Then all you do is post to the `BufferBlock<T>` from your various sources (producers) and make sure you've load tested/configured your block options (`BoundedCapacity`, `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`, `MaxMessagesPerTask`, etc.) accordingly and let TPL Dataflow work its magic. Takes all the heavy lifting out of your hands.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Pipelines approach would help you.

> The Pipeline pattern uses parallel tasks and concurrent queues to
>   process a sequence of input values. Each task implements a stage of
>   the pipeline, and the queues act as buffers that allow the stages of
>   the pipeline to execute concurrently, even though the values are
>   processed in order. You can think of software pipelines as analogous
>   to assembly lines in a factory, where each item in the assembly line
>   is constructed in stages. The partially assembled item is passed from
>   one assembly stage to another. The outputs of the assembly line occur
>   in the same order as that of the inputs.

See following MSDN papers and examples:

- [Pipelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963548.aspx)
- [How to: Use Arrays of Blocking Collections in a Pipeline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460715.aspx)

Comment: I'm not sure I can use this approach, it seems more geared towards scenarios where the processing is staged.  I have what could be visualised as 40 streams interlaced where the processing of each item is the same, but where I'd like to parallelize where each source is a partition.  Except as it's a stream I don't have the array up front to partition.  Unless you can partition on the fly?

Comment: Is item processing time is longer than consuming it from the stream? I'm thinking about consuming items into a queue whcih is observer by multiple tasks, so whilst one task consuming stream - other tasks process the items, am I missing something?

Comment: More like the rate the initial stream adds items can increase, like rush hour.  All the sudden the same street has loads more cars.  But the way I process data all cars of the same colour must be processed in the same order, but they can be split into different more lanes (if I could just build them in my metaphorical highway).