# C# Concurrency - Preferred approach to long running tasks

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, .net-4.5, async-await

When there needs to be an I/O listener running throughout an applications lifetime, what concurrency model is preferred with C# 5.0 running on the 4.5 framework?

I've settled on the idea that a producer-consumer pattern would be best for handling what I receive, but what infrastructure should support it?

Would a simple `Thread thread = new Thread(ThreadStart(method))` be advised? or perhaps a `Task` or `Async/Await` model would be preferred?

It is a bit of a quick fire question, but as I'm early in the design, I'd prefer to make sure the foundation is strong. My gut reaction coming from other languages is that a simple thread running in the background is best, but the plethora of parallel frameworks in C# has thrown me off course.

If of any relevance, the poll time in my application would be handled by the I/O read timeout.

#### Update:

The I/O I refer to is an FTDI device, where bytes may be pushed by the device to the PC at any moment, depending on the state of the on-board controller. As a result, I always need to be ready to pickup the data and process it. The API I'm using is based on the D2XX DLL provided by the FTDI vendor.

Comment: I kinda came across this problem and asked this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5243872/how-to-correctly-clean-up-after-long-running-task-is-cancelled
It's not `C# 5` but uses `TPL`

Note: this only really addresses the long running task and producer consumer aspect of your question.

Comment: What's your I/O listener looks like? What's the API you're using for I/O?

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I've updated the original post to clarify what I mean by I/O (in the sense the work is I/O bound rather than CPU bound).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The I/O I refer to is an FTDI device, where bytes may be pushed by the
>   device to the PC at any moment, depending on the state of the on-board
>   controller. As a result, I always need to be ready to pickup the data
>   and process it. The API I'm using is based on the D2XX DLL provided by
>   the FTDI vendor.

A quick search discovers [this document](http://www.ftdichip.com/Support/Documents/ProgramGuides/D2XX_Programmer's_Guide(FT_000071).pdf). A brief look at it suggests you'd need to open your device device for overlapped I/O, to implement an efficient listener. Here's a relevant sample code from the document (C++):

```
FT_HANDLE ftHandle; // setup by FT_W32_CreateFile for overlapped i/o 
char Buf[256]; 
DWORD dwToRead = 256; 
DWORD dwRead; 
OVERLAPPED osRead = { 0 }; 
osRead.hEvent = CreateEvent (NULL, FALSE, FALSE, NULL); 

if (!FT_W32_ReadFile(ftHandle, Buf, dwToRead, &dwRead, &osRead)) 
{ 
    if (FT_W32_GetLastError(ftHandle) == ERROR_IO_PENDING) 
    { 
        // write is delayed so do some other stuff until ... 
        if (!FT_W32_GetOverlappedResult(ftHandle, &osRead, &dwRead, FALSE))
        { 
            // error 
        } 
        else 
        { 
            if (dwToRead == dwRead)
            { 
                // FT_W32_ReadFile OK 
            } 
            else
            { 
                // FT_W32_ReadFile timeout 
            } 
        } 
    } 
} 
else 
{ 
    // FT_W32_ReadFile OK 
}
```

The key point here is this comment: "*// write **is delayed** so do some other stuff until ...* " [BTW, I believe it's a typo, there should be *read* instead of *write* there].

**How to handle this delay? To make your listener asynchronous, you'd have to wait for the kernel event object asynchronously**. I just [answered a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21881615/1768303) on how to do it efficiently. In your case, it might look like this (a sketch in C#):

```
async Task<Data> ReadFtdiAsync()
{
    // ...

    var completedMre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    osRead.hEvent = completedMre.SafeWaitHandle.DangerousGetHandle();

    if (!FT_W32_ReadFile(ftHandle, Buf, dwToRead, ref dwRead, ref osRead)) 
    { 
        if (FT_W32_GetLastError(ftHandle) == ERROR_IO_PENDING) 
        { 
            // asynchronous completion
            // read is delayed, so await

            var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();

            ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(
                completedMre, 
                (s, t) => tcs.SetResult(true),
                null, Timeout.Infinite, true)

            // resume asynchronously when the event is signalled
            await tcs.Task;

            if (!FT_W32_GetOverlappedResult(ftHandle, ref osRead, ref dwRead, FALSE))
            { 
                // error 
                throw new InvalidOperationException("I/O error");
            } 
            else 
            { 
                if (dwToRead == dwRead)
                { 
                    // FT_W32_ReadFile OK 

                    // retrieve and return the data
                    return data;
                } 
                else
                { 
                    // FT_W32_ReadFile timeout
                    throw new TimeoutException(); 
                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 
    else 
    { 
        // synchronous completion

        // retrieve and return the data
        // or handle an error
        return data;
    } 
}
```

This code may and should be improved with proper timeout and cancellation logic. Then you can simply call `ReadFtdiAsync` in a loop:

```
while (true)
{
    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
    var data = await ReadFtdiAsync(cancellationToken);

    // the execution will resume here likely on a different thread
    ProcessData(data);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

If I interpret your "I/O listener" correctly, then you should just always have a continuous asynchronous read operation going. No thread is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

For I/O is always better to use [I/O completion ports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198%28VS.85%29.aspx) that in .net are wrapped in methods like

```
Stream.BeginRead
Stream.BeginWrite
```

or for .net 4.5

```
Stream.ReadAsync
Stream.WriteAsync
```

is a very bad idea to put a thread or a task to wait for a synchronous I/O operation

Comment: "is always better" Not at all. This answer is very one-sided.